# Laravel CSRF value empty

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5.1

I am trying to add csrf in my laravel web app as meta tag -

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

but the value is empty when I browse it -

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="">
```

I have also tried adding in login form also -
 as `{!! csrf_filed() !!}` or

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

but in both case value is null.
I am using Angularjs in front end, does it have to do anything with that?

Comment: Write it like this :                                                                                                    <input type="text" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">    or              <input type="text" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">          and see the value

Comment: CSRF token is stored in the session, check if the session store is well configured

Comment: @vikrammistry I tried that also same result may be session store problem. But how to check that?

Comment: You don't need to set CSRF token for AngularJS, because starting from Laravel 5.0 it automatically sets X-CSRF-TOKEN, which is used by Laravel instead of CSRF token. You can check more info here - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: @naneri yeah I saw that, but is there any way I can verify it? I mean I  want to check if csrf token is validated in every Ajax request.

Comment: Very first you need to print the csrf token because laravel automaticallly passed the csrf token and if it is getting printed, then in the ajax request try to pass that token.

Comment: Now I am see everything clearly. If I want to verify `CSRF` token then laravel route must include `web` middleware group in its route. This `web` is defined in `Http\Kernel.php` as `'web' => [\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,],`. The `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie can be seen in resource now.The problem was not including `web` middleware in root route. Anyway thanks for helping :).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put you routes inside the route group 'middleware':

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    // your routes here

});
```

And run this:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 2):

We also get empty value in `csrf_token` if we are in the `404` page. This usually happens when you are trying to perform logout action, the form is in `header.blade.php` and we are accessing the `404` page. Try going back to the index page and see if the `csrf_token` is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was trying to handle page expired by flushing the session manually. When I flushed the session from controller and inspect the html form then I was getting empty _token value and when session flush code is removed from controller it was working fine. Also in documentation it states csrf will be generated for active user and when the session is expired or flushed then empty value is generated. For some geeks it also case with not using the middleware web as mentioned in the answer above.