# Laravel @csrf empty value

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, csrf, csrf-token

**The result generated by `@csrf` in Blade**

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="">
```

Also tried `{!! csrf_field() !!}` and `{{ csrf_field() }}` but still there is no value .

I know this question is already asked [Laravel CSRF value empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541028/laravel-csrf-value-empty), but the solution for that did not work for me.

**`app/Http/Kernel.php`**

```
'web' => [
  \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
  \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
  \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
  \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
  \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

Comment: Apply the `@csrf` within the `<form>`? Could you attach a Blade example?

Comment: in your controller before you serve your blade file try doing `dd(session()->all())` to see if the session is actually working (CSRF tokens are based on the session). Also make sure your route is defined in your `web.php` file not the `api.php` file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the web middleware group, which includes the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware, is applied to your routes. In your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file, the web middleware group should be applied to the necessary routes.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

After this try clearning cache of application and regenrate key

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: this is how it looks 

   'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

Comment: @ArsalanKhan Please post such info inside your question, not in a comment, thanks

Comment: @brombeer , I edited the question

Comment: try regenrating keym clear your entire application cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear

Comment: works for me. tried clearing the cache and regenerated the key

Comment: I don't understand why this solves the problem. Your first response regarding `middlewareGroups` doesn't do anything new. Clearing the cache is just a suggestion. Please explain how this addresses the issue the asker is facing.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code inside you will see that the `csrf_token` is created if a session has been created. I think this is the **main reason**. Check the `.env` file and the driver for the session. If it is a `file` check the permissions for the storage directory.

Also make sure you are using `web` guard. Since it defaults to `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class`, or include it in your active group if it is an `api` or something else.

**Without a session, there will be no csrf token.**

```php
// src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php

function csrf_field()
{
        return new HtmlString('<input type="hidden" name="_token" value=''.csrf_token().''>'');
}

function csrf_token()
{
    $session = app('session');

    if (isset($session)) {
        return $session->token();
    }

    throw new RuntimeException('Application session store not set.');
}
```

You can check it out

```php
app('session')->start();

dd(app('session')->token());
```